# How to monitor SQL Server-side profile as a job on the instance using powershell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, automation

I have tried with create profile trace T-SQL Query statements.. But I need to monitor server side profile trace monitoring using powershell code.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you mean read the trace file from Powershell? That can be done using SMO [TraceServer.InitializeAsReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.trace.traceserver.initializeasreader.aspx).

Comment: Why a profile trace and not Extended Events? Or, better question - what are you attempting to capture/what problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: I need to capture Audit_login from server side profile trace using powershell .. It needs to capture all  sql servers in that domain too